# Implementing Selection Sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I did this sort function in C++ for **Linked List**

```
void sort()
{
    node* ctr;
    node* innerctr;
    info temp;
    node* max;
    ctr = start;
    while(ctr!=NULL)
    {
        innerctr=ctr->next;
        max=ctr;
            while(innerctr!=NULL)
            {

                if((innerctr->student.name) > (max->student.name))
                {
                    max=innerctr;

                }


                innerctr=innerctr->next;


            }

            //swapping...


        ctr=ctr->next;
    }
}
```

I need to do something similar in Java and I want to use the LinkedList ready class but I am a bit confused because there are no pointers.

Comment: "There are no pointers" is a sketchy statement, especially fun are NullPointerExceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With as few modifications as possible, nearly the same thing in Java:

```
class Student {String name = "Joe Doe";}
class Node {
    Node next;
    Student student;
}
class Info {}
public class NodeSorter {

    Node start; 

    void sort()
    {
        Node ctr;
        Node innerctr;
        Info temp;
        Node max;
        ctr = start;

        while (ctr != null)
        {
            innerctr = ctr.next;
            max=ctr;

            while (innerctr != null)
            {
                if ((innerctr.student.name).compareTo (max.student.name) > 0)
                {
                    max = innerctr;
                }
                innerctr=innerctr.next;
            }
            //swapping...
            ctr = ctr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

- some dummy classes (Student, Info)
- Node would normally be generic, not fixed to Student.
- classnames with Capitals.
- methods and attributes are just delimited with dot
- comparision with compareTo (for non-numbers)

And here is the improved version, with Type "Student" as parameter for the Node:

```
class Student implements Comparable <Student> {
    String name = "Joe Doe";
    public int compareTo (Student other) {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return name.compareTo (other.name);
    }   
}
class Node <T> {
    Node <T> next;
    T value;
}
class Info {}
public class NodeSorter {

    Node <Comparable> start;    

    void sort ()
    {
        Node <Comparable> ctr;
        Node <Comparable> innerctr;
        Info temp;
        Node <Comparable> max;
        ctr = start;

        while (ctr != null)
        {
            innerctr = ctr.next;
            max=ctr;

            while (innerctr != null)
            {
                if ((innerctr.value).compareTo (max.value) > 0)
                {
                    max = innerctr;
                }
                innerctr=innerctr.next;
            }
            //swapping...
            ctr = ctr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the unspecified 'start' is inherited from you.

Answer (score 1):

Check [java.util.Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). There's no need to implement sorting and such in Java, it's all in the JDK.

Comment: @Ahmed, sometimes the best lesson is when not to re-invent the wheel. ;)

Comment: You need to know the wheel first.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know what means > for name in your example
- Below code uses selecting min index not max index like in your case - so you should change a  bit this solution. But idea is still the same

source from [this site](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/31arrayselectionsort.html)

```
public static void selectionSort2(int[] x) {
    for (int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;      // Index of smallest remaining value.
        for (int j=i+1; j<x.length; j++) {
            if (x[minIndex] > x[j]) {
                minIndex = j;  // Remember index of new minimum
            }
        }
        if (minIndex != i) { 
            //...  Exchange current element with smallest remaining.
            int temp = x[i];
            x[i] = x[minIndex];
            x[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```